# Html to RTF conversion

Tags: html, rtf

What is the word(RTF/doc) equivalent of Html for the below tag.

```
<IMG SRC = "planet.jpg"  align="left" Width = "600">
```

Comment: Are you wanting to leave it as a linked image or embed it in the .rtf?

Comment: @Henry: What are you trying to determine that you can't get by creating an html file with your IMG tag, load it into Word and then save it as rtf?

Answer (score 6):

Are you really sure you want that answer ?

Well, as a start, the equivalent of :

```
<html><IMG SRC = "planet.jpg"  align="left" Width = "600"></html>
```

is...

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1036\deflangfe1036\deftab708{\fonttbl{\f0\froman\fprq2\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2510;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs24\par
\lang12\f1\fs22{\pict\wmetafile8\picw185\pich53\picwgoal8989\pichgoal2569 
0100090000036c02000000000c02000000000c02000026060f000e04574d464301000000000001
00ef460000000001000000ec03000000000000ec030000010000006c0000000000000000000000
06000000010000000000000000000000f60000004500000020454d4600000100ec0300000c0000
0001000000000000000000000000000000900600001a0400005102000072010000000000000000
0000000000001a0b0900f0a60500460000002c00000020000000454d462b014001001c00000010
0000000210c0db01000000600000006000000046000000fc010000f0010000454d462b22400400
0c000000000000001e4009000c00000000000000244001000c0000000000000030400200100000
00040000000000803f214007000c0000000000000008400005480100003c0100000210c0db0100
00000000000000000000000000000000000001000000ffd8ffe000104a46494600010100000100
010000ffdb00430001010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101ffdb00430101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101ffc000110800020007030122000211
01031101ffc400150001010000000000000000000000000000000affc400141001000000000000
00000000000000000000ffc4001501010100000000000000000000000000000406ffc400141101
00000000000000000000000000000000ffda000c03010002110311003f00b58013e43fffd90840
010824000000180000000210c0db01000000030000000000000000000000000000001b40000040
000000340000000100000002000000000000bf000000bf0000e0400000004003000000000000b3
000000b3ffffdf40000000b3000000b3ffffff3f2100000008000000620000000c000000010000
00150000000c00000004000000150000000c00000004000000510000008c000000000000000000
000006000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000007000000020000005000000034
0000008400000008000000000000002000cc000700000002000000280000000700000002000000
0100040000000000000000000000000000000000030000000000000000000000ffffff00e4ecec
0022222220222222204c0000006400000000000000000000000600000001000000000000000000
000007000000020000002900aa0000000000000000000000803f00000000000000000000803f00
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000220000000c000000
ffffffff460000001c00000010000000454d462b024000000c000000000000000e000000140000
000000000010000000140000000400000003010800050000000b0200000000050000000c020200
0700030000001e00040000000701040004000000070104002b000000410b2000cc000200070000
000000020007000000000028000000070000000200000001000400000000000000000000000000
00000000030000000000000000000000ffffff00e4ecec0022222220222222200c000000400929
00aa000000000000000200070000000000040000002701ffff030000000000
}\lang1036\f0\fs24\par
\par
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample with a *linked (not embedded)* picture, named mypic.jpg and placed in c:\tmp. This sample works with MSWord. Does not work with Wordpad

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1040{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\qr\lang16\f0\fs22 This test is right aligned:\par
{\field{\*\fldinst{INCLUDEPICTURE "c:\\\\tmp\\\\mypic.jpg" MERGEFORMAT \\d \\w200  \\pm1 \\px0 \\py0 \\pw0}}}\par
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the question makes sense, because word/rtf doesn't work the same way as html. For example, you assign a pixel width to your image, which is not possible and doesn't make any sense in word, as it is primarily aimed for paper/print and sets sizes in inches or centimeters.p

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to embed a styled word document into a webpage, I'd recommend signing up for a [Slideshare account](http://www.slideshare.net/), uploading your document there, and then customizing their embed code and pasting into your site.

Comment: Better yet, convert it to a PDF file and just do it that way.